Apache Nifi Processor FetchFile unable to read file with whitespace in filename
Is this a limitation that Apache Nifi Processor FetchFile cannot fetch file with whitespace in filename ?.
I am getting an error below
FetchFile[id=992e9634-0191-1000-f45b-de7990f121e5] Could not fetch file /tmp/space0/space00/file\ with\ space from file system for FlowFile[filename=b0835036-2915-4812-ad96-35dd87fc847f] because the file does not exist; routing to not.found
I tried to pass different filename escaping whitespace like below.
None of them works
/tmp/space0/space00/file\ with\ space
"/tmp/space0/space00/file with space"
/tmp/space0/space00/file with space

Can you provide more details on what you've tried? Using the latest version of NiFi on MacOS I cannot replicate the behaviour you describe. Fetching a file with a space in its name works for me. I didn't escape the name in any way. Are you sure the file exists?
